# Sprint Boot - Aws Elastic Search

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, boot

I successfully setup up AWS Elastic search and I can query elastic search on AWS using curl from terminal:

```
curl -XPUT -u 'admin:xxxx'
    'https://search-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxu.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com/xxxxx/_doc/1'
     -d '{"name": "product", "description": "crema..."}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

In the project I have the following dependency;

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and running an elastic search instance on my mac I can connect to elastic search using the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticClient extends ElasticsearchConfiguration {
    
    @Override
    public ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration() {
       
        return ClientConfiguration.builder()
                .connectedTo("localhost:9200")
                .build();
    }
}
```

In order to connect to elastic search on AWS I tried several confgurations including the deprecated `RestHighLevelClient` without success.

It is possible to connect to AWS using Spring boot and basic http authentication like I've done using **curl** command from terminal? I would like to implement `public ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration()` with the right configuration in order to connect to my elastic search hosted on AWS.

Thanks

Comment: Is your client application running behind some firewall or proxy ? May be check if the port and host are reachable from the application. Also double check the SSL, perhaps your cluster require some certificate for authorization.

Comment: From terminal i can run curl...

Comment: Your ES url starts with `https`, is SSL over http configured ? Are you providing some sort of switch or certificates in your curl command ?

Comment: no just curl, see above (https://search-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxu.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com/xxxxx/_doc/1), it uses basic authentication

Comment: Ahh hold on, you are trying to access AWS Elasticsearch, do you mean Opensearch or is it Elastic's Elasticsearch deployed on AWS?

Comment: Elastic Search, I don't know pro/contro of these two alternatives

Comment: Well, for starters, Opensearch (earier OpenDistro) is an AWS service offering which is essentially a forked version of Elasticsearch/Kibana 7.10.

For more information, please read: https://www.elastic.co/amazon-opensearch-service